# Creating criteria for SQL SELECT statement using selections in listbox

Tags: vba, ms-access, listbox, criteria

I am trying to enable the user to select employees from a listbox and then press a command button that will run a query that includes the selected employees (trimmers) in the a WHERE statement.

I've attempted this using a loop that adds the selected list items to a string variable that I plan to use in my SQL WHERE statement. I add " or like" to the variable each time it loops through a list selection. My problem is that I don't want the first item to have "or" in front of it. I want the first item to return "Like TrimmerName1" and the rest of the items to return " or like TrimmerName2" etc.

Maybe there is a totally different approach that would be better. I'm not sure. I'm pretty new to VBA and this is my second time posting here. Any help is appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
Dim varTrimmers As Variant
Dim varTrimmer As String
Dim VCriteria As String

For Each varTrimmers In Me.lstTrimmers.ItemsSelected
varTrimmer = Me.lstTrimmers.ItemData(varTrimmers)


VCriteria = VCriteria & " or like " & "'" & varTrimmer & "'"

Next varTrimmers
```

Comment: Right on homie. That worked nicely.

Comment: Glad to hear. Please remember to accept an answer so that the question does not remain open.

Answer (score 0):

When it's finished looping, remove the first 4 characters.

```
Dim varTrimmers As Variant
Dim varTrimmer As String
Dim VCriteria As String

For Each varTrimmers In Me.lstTrimmers.ItemsSelected
  varTrimmer = Me.lstTrimmers.ItemData(varTrimmers)
  VCriteria = VCriteria & " or like " & "'" & varTrimmer & "'"
Next varTrimmers
VCriteria = Mid$(VCriteria, 4, Len(VCriteria))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim varTrimmers As Variant
Dim varTrimmer As String
Dim VCriteria As String

For Each varTrimmers In Me.lstTrimmers.ItemsSelected
varTrimmer = Me.lstTrimmers.ItemData(varTrimmers)


VCriteria = VCriteria & " or like " & "'" & varTrimmer & "'"

Next varTrimmers

VCriteria = Right([VCriteria], Len([VCriteria]) - 4)
```